# Change "SIC Code" Field To "NAICS Code" In Organization/Contact

Tags: wordpress, contacts, core, fields

So, the SIC Code appeared as an issue early on dealing with EU folks, but I never found anything other than some postings in the old wiki. I am in the US and while Public companies sometimes deal with SIC, the standard is NAICS. I want to change the name of the "SIC Code" to NAICS Code. A bit of background is that [NAICS replaced SIC in 1997](https://www.census.gov/naics/) for the US, Canada, and Mexico and is the general type of trade like a carpenter. [It has 6 digits](https://www.naics.com/ufaq/why-are-some-naics-codes-only-5-digits-long/#:%7E:text=The%20first%20two%20digits%20designate,NAICS%20code%20contains%20six%20digits.). I know the "SIC Code" field is set to 8 digits. Not a big deal, but would be **GREAT** to be able to change the length of the field as well! The PSC is a federal supply code. The PSC is a hierarchy set up by the US government. All of our Membership are associated in the trades industries. I can set that up as a custom field. I would also like to be able to search by NAICS if I can change the name of the field.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but why not just ignore SIC and create a searchable custom field for NAICS?

Comment: Primarily for the Look and Feel and the amount of data to pre-populate would be astronomical. Thanks though for input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do 'word replacements' under 'customize data and screens'.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Duh SMH! Excellent and thanks for the input!

Comment: Just wanted to add that this type of edit is Case Sensitive for anyone else whom ends up here and thinks that it does not work!